Which one should i use in protobuf? oneof, Any, Map?
I have a .proto, there is one message in it named Event.
message Event{
    string id=1;
    string param=2;
}

The param field of Event is a model defined by biz layer, different biz has different model, for example:
data class Cart(val size:Int, val int price:Int)
data class Goods(val id:String, val name:String)

The above is two biz Model, in order to wrap them with Event, i turn the model into json string like the following:
val cartString = Cart(1,2).toJsonString()
val goodsString = Goods("a1","apple").toJsonString()
val cartEvent = Event {
    id = "a"
    param = cartString
}
val goodsEvent = Event {
    id = "b"
    param = goodsString
}

The number of different biz model could be over 200+.
Is this a good way to do it?
Or should i use Any and be will 200+ biz message?
Or Map is beter way? Like :
message Event{
    string id=1;
    map<string,string> param=3;
}


Questions that solicit opinions are discouraged on Stack overflow (because there's no definitive answer). Another option for you to consider is Any. You are effectively enveloping messages within Event. Using string is effectively type-less. Using oneof could become burdensome but preserves types (at the expense of extended switch statements). Any provides a means to define arbitrary messages to be carried but retains the schema mechanism at the expense of some complexity managing the unique identifiers of the message's types.

The answer will depend on the goals you aim to achieve using protobuf.

Protobuf as encapsulation format for passing data to e.g. gRPC: JSON inside string is fine, it avoids having to maintain the protobuf schema.
Dynamic translation from JSON to protobuf: map is the closest equivalent, but there is rarely any benefit compared to JSON string.
Well defined schema for use, but not extension by other programs: oneof with specific messages for each event type.
Well defined schema for use and extension by multiple programs: Any with specific messages for each event type.

This list goes in the order increasing effort to implement.
It is also influenced on what the other side will do with the data. If you already have an underlying model of the events and conversion to/from JSON and this model is available to all of the programs involved, there is no point converting to protobuf and back. But if the opposite side doesn't have such model available, you need to specify a schema - either in JSON or in protobuf.
